# Como añadir un passwordToggle en android studio

Tags: android-studio, androidx

He intentado añadir la libreria design pero me da un error en el que me dice que tengo que migrar a librerias de androidx, entonces me gustaria saber como puedo poner un passwordtoggle de otra forma o en caso contrario como migrar a las librerias de androidx

La libreria usada es **'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'** aun no entiendo que ocurre exactamente asi que te escribo lo que me dice el android studio:

> Version 28(intended for android pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help whit this Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling whit a version of the Android support libraries that is not the lastest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion)

He realizado la refactorizacion y me a cambiado la libreria a una llamada **'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'** es lo unico que a hecho, pero aun asi no me da la opcion de poner app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que has intentado, para tener una idea de lo que estas realizando y darte una respuesta acertada, revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puede que este metiendo una libreria que no es, la correcta es:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Y para el control seria algo asi

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/et_passwordInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_usuarioInputLayour"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/editTextPassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Donde en el `TextInputEditText` hay una propiedad que se debe de poner

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: La libreria estaba bien aun no entiendo que ocurre exactamente asi que te escribo lo que me dice el android studio: Version 28(intended for android pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help whit this Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling whit a version of the Android support libraries that is not the

Comment: lastest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion)
E realizado la refactorizacion y me a cambiado la libreria es lo unico que a hecho, pero aun asi no me da la opcion de poner  app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"